# Set History Tracking - fields not showing-up in related list

Tags: custom-object, administration, history-tracking

I have a custom object in which I have selected few <20 fields to track. But I don't see the custom object fields in the "Related List Properties" for the Activity History

here is what I have done:

1. Enable Track Field History option under option feature on the Custom object.
2. Click Set History Tracking in the Custom Fields & Relationships section and checked all those fields for tracking.
3. Add Custom object History related list on the detail page.

I have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The history tracking doesn't show a column for each checked field, but rather creates a history record for each changed field (that's set to track history) when an edit is made to a record

These records are saved in the system generated Object_API_Name__History object, and will be shown in the Object History related list, rather than the Activity History related list

Comment: so what is the Activity History for ?

Comment: so if I understood correctly, you saying the tracking fields will be only show in the "Modification History" related list ?

Comment: The history related list will have the name of the object that the fields belong to in the name, e.g. Account History for the Accounts object (not sure if you're looking at a custom object called "Modification"?). The Activity History related list tracks all closed/completed Activity types of records (like Tasks, Emails, etc.)